# CodeIgniter routing as subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

Let me explain my scenario. I have a project to create blog with CodeIgniter as a SaaS. So multiple user can create their blog with it. Now I would like to give them an opportunity to show their blog like, domain.com/name1 , domain.com/name2 etc.

My default controller is auth which take care of authentication related task. So domain.com/name1 generally try to find a method name1 from auth controller. But I would like to call "loadblog" method from another controller "subfolder" when I get domain.com/name1 or name2 etc.

How can I rewrite this URL domain.com/name1 to subfolder controller's loadblog method and the "name1" as parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual?

Comment: @Tiger I tried to rewrite rules on .htaccess but fails :(
I made a controller "Subfolder". I know generally name1 should be the default controller's method but here I would like to connect this to my subfolder controller's index method and name1 should be its param.

Comment: @Sparky Can you please point me which part of the document should I read for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make use of _remap() function of controller for dynamic routing

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls

For more details, you can refer the following example:
http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-remove-index-php-minimize-url/

Comment: I tried _remap() but still fails. My default controller is auth, so I use _remap() function in that controller but it only triggerwith domain.com/auth/anything not with domain.com/anything.
I hope you got my point.
Thanks

Comment: You can refer the example mentioned in the following link: http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-remove-index-php-minimize-url/

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I already solve my issue by editing /config/routes.php
First I need to declare all my controller route manually and then I add the following line,
$route['(:any)'] = 'subfolder/index/$1';
So domain.com/abc point to subfolder controller index method and pass abc as parameter.
I think I can accept your answer as it helps me to think how to cope my problem.
Thanks again :)

Comment: Pleasure to help you. And thanks for defining your approach to solve this issue.